# Date is not binding correctly while generating report in MVC5?

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

Hi i have one view called **DailyVisitReport** . it contain 2 fields called **FromDate** and **ToDate**. I am generating report depend upon the dates. I am using Crystal Report 2010. In normal Local Machine run it working fine after deploying my application in web server it showing empty report. I will explain my issue clearly.

I upload my application in online using Web server. So I purchased Virtual Private Server from Godaddy. I upload my application in online using Remote desktop connection by purchased web server IP address (from Godaddy).

Before i got one error while generating report after i deploying my application in web server that error is mention below.

[image]

so i asked many forums and search google. Many of them suggest me to add CrystalDecistion.ReportAppServer.CommLayer dll in assembly folder of the web server system and also refer that in Web.config File.I also did the same. Again i deploy my appliation in web server  and try to generate the report. This time it didnt show any error and also generate the empty report.

[image]

The issue is date is not binding correctly. The Date Format which i send to controller is 01-mar-16 from Fromdate and Todate. But the date format which is retrieving from db is  different eg 08/12/2016 and also it coming with time.I am saving Date without time in db.But while retrieving it will come with one default time.

So i convert the date format in sql as string format using

```
Replace(Convert(varchar(50), vf.VisitingDate,6), ' ', '-')As VisitingDate
```

And also i change the VisitingDate Format from String to date while retrieving. Now the format of date while retrieving from db and format of fromdate and to date both are same.I normal local machine run its working perfectly. But it showing empty report after deploying in web server.And one thing that is if i didnt select any date and click ok button means it shows all the data (which is in the table) in report in web server

**My Controller Code**

```
 public ActionResult VisitSummaryReport()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetDates(VisitorsViewModel VisitorsVM)
    {
        var fromdt = Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MMM/yy}", VisitorsVM.FromDate));
        var todt = Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MMM/yy}", VisitorsVM.ToDate));
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=S192-169-143-12\WAFEEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CRM;User ID=sa;Password=Wafe@win;");
        //SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.0.73\SQLEXPRESS,14330;Initial Catalog=CRM;User ID=sa;Password=wafewin;");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Parameters.Add("@fromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = fromdt;
            command.Parameters.Add("@toDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = todt;
            command.CommandText = "Select * from  [View_VisitorsForm]  Where CAST(VisitingDate AS Date) >= @fromDate and  CAST(VisitingDate AS Date) <= @toDate";


            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adp.Fill(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Sales/CrystalReports/rpt_VisitSummaryCrystalReport.rpt"));
        rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
        Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

**My web config**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->
   <configuration>
   <configSections>
   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyCRM.csdl|res://*/MyCRM.ssdl|res://*/MyCRM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.73\SQLEXPRESS,14330;initial catalog=CRM;user id=sa;password=wafewin;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>

     <appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
   <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
     <system.web>

<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />

 <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
 <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
 <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
   </assemblies>
   </compilation>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
     <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
   </handlers>
   <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
     <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    </entityFramework>
   </configuration>
```

Still i am getting Empty report in web server. I tried my level best to explain my issue.Please any one understand my isssue and help me to resolve this problem.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: you have to add the assembly in your web.config look your local web.config there should be assembly you can added those to your uploaded web.config

Comment: I update my web.config file. Please have a check and tell which refernce i miss to add

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add this assemblies to your web config and check
Note : please change the version what you have use

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: And have forgot to tell one thing thwt id if i didnt select any date and click ok button means it shows all the data  in report in web server